# (Panel or time series) cointegration including one lagged variable

Tags: time-series, references, panel-data, cointegration

I have conviction that one of the variables in my vector can affect the rest only if it is lagged. For example, lets imagine a agriculture product which is planted in April of the previous year and harvest in February of the following year. And for its development, it is critical the rain during the year when the plant is planted So, I want to investigate cointegration between the rain in the previous year (Xt-1) and the harvest in the following year (Yt).

I think this is just fine. However, I always have seen the investigation of cointegration in contemporary values of the variables in the vector. In the following link,

[Cointegration with lagged variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285582/cointegration-with-lagged-variables)

a professor provides a clear explanation indicating the validity of my framework, but I haven't found any published paper applying this framework. Indeed, that link is the only reference I have found in this topic. So, I worry about the rejection of potential reviewers. Therefore, I would like to gather suggestions of published papers using this. In addition, suggestions of literature on this topic are welcomed.

Finally, I want to apply this in a panel data framework and using both Engle and Granger residual based framework and Johansen Fisher panel cointegration tests. However, if this framework is just fine in pure time series analysis, it should work in panel data also.

Very much thank you in advance,