# VECM: alpha is a 0-vector? cointegration rank = $k$ even though $X_t$ is I(1)?

Tags: cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I'm trying to wrap my head around the VECM model by doing some simple examples. In this exercise I'm taking the log prices of 2 assets, A and B. These prices are clearly not stationary, for example `asset A`:
[image: asset A]

(For the rest of the explanation I'm using the `statsmodels` library, but my questions are about the fundamentals behind the model, not about the use of the library itself.)

Now, as I said I have a dataframe with 2 columns of log-price data, one for `asset A` and one for `asset B`.

1. I can check for the cointegration rank of my data. First of all, if I calculate the cointegration rank for 1 lagged difference I get a rank of 2. From what I understand this implies that the data (vector `Xt`, or the log-prices themselves) is already stationary and the model isn't informative and hence we should study `Xt` directly (Analysis of Financial Time Series, Tsay, section 8.6). How is this possible in this case if both my series are log-prices and hence hardly stationary (I(0))? Now, if I select 2 lagged differences I get the expected rank of one, which basically means there is 1 cointegration relationship between the 2 series
2. And here comes my second question, how come that the lag matters
   when calculating the cointegrating rank? Any resources where I could
   see this? My understanding is that `alpha` and `beta` are `k x m` (k
   = number of assets, m = cointegrating factors) so I don't see where the lag comes here, also because for a cointegrating relationship
   one would look at the log-prices at the same `t`

   ```
   from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import select_coint_rank, VECM

   select_coint_rank(df_vecm, det_order=0, k_ar_diff=1) #-----> rank = 2
   select_coint_rank(df_vecm, det_order=0, k_ar_diff=2) #-----> rank = 1
   ```
3. In this example, I'm running a VECM model with `cointegration rank = 1` and 2 lagged differences. According to these results the `alphas`
   of the model are not significantly different from 0. If I'm not mistaken, the `alphas` are basically the speed of adjustment of the long-term (cointegration) relationship. Does this mean that according to these results there isn't such a long-run relationship and these 2 variables are not cointegrated?

   ```
   vecmodel = VECM(df_vecm, coint_rank=1, k_ar_diff=2)
   vecfit = vecmodel.fit()
   ```
4. My cointegrating vector $\beta$ is `[1, 2.02]`. I guess since the
   cointegration rank of my matrix is 1 and there is one cointegrating
   relationship, it's normal that the first element of $\beta$ is `1`
   and common in all the VECM models?

Here are the VECM results:

[image: VECM results]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A brief answer:

1. You logic is correct. In theory, this should not happen. In practice, this may be caused by estimation imprecision and/or low power of tests.
2. In theory, the lag does not matter. As long as the lag is finite, the appropriate linear combination of the cointegrated series is a finite sum of I(0) elements, and that is still I(0). (See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285582/cointegration-with-lagged-variables/285589#285589) answer of mine for details.) In practice, see point 1.
3. In theory, the $\alpha$s should not be *jointly* zero, though one of them may be zero. In practice, see point 1.
4. Yes, it is standard practice to normalize the first element of $\beta$ to 1. You could always multiple $\alpha$ by a constant and divide $\beta$ by the same constant to obtain the same behavior of the cointegrated system, so normalizing $\beta$ this way is just a matter of convention.

Comment: Thank you Richard, very clear. One last clarification: Is it correct to assume that if all the $\alpha$s are not significantly different from 0, there is no cointegrating relationship between the variables? How can this be understood together with the information of `0 < coint_rank < k` ? From your point #1, this would probably mean that the cointegration test for the rank is not accurate and it found a cointegration relationship where there isn't none, right? Thanks again

Comment: @Hiperfly, you basically got everything right by yourself; I just briefly pointed out a couple of things. Indeed, if the cointegration rank $0<r<k$, then the $\alpha$s cannot be jointly zero. This should not happen in theory or given infinite data. If that happens, the possible causes are indicated under point 1.